# How Can Spring MVC Handle Requests to URLs Generated by the Angular Router?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, angular

I have a Spring (v, 4.3.2 & Java 8) application that serves up an Angular2 single page application front end that has multiple routes (say `/foo`, `/bar` and `/baz`, one of which requires a parameter to render (`/baz/x` where x is the identifier of the resource to retrieve).

The html is served up with a standard Spring MVC `@Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/foo", "/bar", "/baz/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(@PathVariable Optional<String> id) {
    return "index";
}
```

and views are resolved using:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

If the browser reloads from the `/`, `/foo` or `/bar` routes, the controller properly returns the `index` page and angular resolves the view for the route as expected. However, if the browser reloads from one of the `baz` routes that contain a paramenter, the server prepends `baz` to the  resource path (e.g. `/baz/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp`) which, results in a 404 error.

I've tried refactoring the `baz` request mappings info into an annotation on a distinct (identical) method and using wildcards in the request mapping (e.g. `/**` and `baz/*` ), but always get the same result. Regardless of the request mapping, Spring seems unaware that it is appending `baz` into the path, as the logs contain:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'index'; URL [WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView - Forwarding to resource [WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'index'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem - omitting the leading slash from the prefix argument string causes the issue. For proper configuration the argument should be:

```
viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
```